# Can we run pyspark on a remote server from apache airflow?

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow

My organisation's apache airflow is installed in the server let's assume *abc*. I have a piece of pyspark code that used to run on a different cluster with master on a different server let's assume *xyz*. I am having difficulty in running the program from apache airflow as lots of errors are showing jars not found and error in connecting to the remote server. The spark master's configuration is as follows:

```
def session_open():

spark = SparkSession \
       .builder \
       .appName("Program_Single_View" ) \
       .master("spark://xyz:7077") \
       .config("spark.executor.memory", "14g") \
       .config("spark.cores.max", "6")  \
       .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g")  \
       .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "384")  \
       .config("spark.local.dir","/datadrive")\
       .config("spark.default.parallelism","60") \
       .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","36") \
       .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true") \
       .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","1g") \
       .config("spark.network.timeout", "100000000")\
       .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","10000000")\
       .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize","4g") \
       .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC') \
       .config("spark.driver.supervise","true")\
       .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/datadrive/PROD/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar") \
       .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/datadrive/PROD/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar") \
       .getOrCreate()

return spark
```

Please help me as I am new to airflow. How can I run the pyspark remotely from server abc on server xyz. The jars and other paths are all present in the xyz server. It's a big piece of code so sharing only the spark session.

The below are the imports for airflow:

````
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import pendulum
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator```

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
}

localtz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
with DAG('PSV_all_server_ETL', default_args=default_args, description='etl', schedule_interval=None,
         start_date=dt(2022, 6, 21, tzinfo=localtz),
         catchup=False, tags=['PSV']) as dag:

    program_single_view_execution = PythonOperator(
        task_id="program_single_view_execution",
        python_callable=program_single_view_execution,
    )

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='Start',
    )

    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='End',
    )

    start >> program_single_view_execution >> end ```

using the above for airflow.
````

Comment: First you have to test your code(looks you have a python script) outside of airflow. Execute it from remote server abc. If this works, then it is just a matter of executing the python script/file via a BashOperator.

Comment: The code runs daily on a remote server. I am not able to integrate it with airflow properly. If you be kind enough, please tell me some resources about bash operator and where am I doing wrong in the current airflow script

Comment: Don't integrate yet with airflow. Create a script(python in your case) that you want to be executed in remote server. Once that is working. Then you can just trigger that script and as long as airflow can access that script.